# Problems porting code from Python 2.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

I have a fragment of code which loads data from a .csv file.
It's written for Python 2.7 but in Python 3.6 does not work.

```
def load_new_data(self):
    full = list()

    with open(self.filename, 'rb') as csv_in:
        myreader2 = csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=';')

        count = 0
        for row in myreader2:
            if count == 0:
                headers = row[1:]
                count += 1
            elif count == 1:
                count += 1
            else:
                current_row = row[1:-1]
                full.append(current_row)
                count += 1

    new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(full, columns=headers)
    new_df = new_df.iloc[1:, :80]

    self.fill_in_blanks(new_df)
    new_df = dp.remove_inc_variables(new_df, .1)
    print '\t Removing incomplete variables.'

    for i in new_df.columns:
        try:
            new_df.loc[:, i] = new_df.loc[:, i].astype(float)
        except:
            pass
    return new_df
```

the error I get is:

```
212 
213             count = 0
--> 214             for row in myreader2:
215                 if count == 0:
216                     headers = row[1:]

Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in 
text mode?)
```

I did try changing the 'rb' to 'r' and 'rt' and even deleting it, as other posts here suggest, but with no success...

Comment: changing rb to r in your code worked for me check it @https://repl.it/repls/MicroNeatExam

Comment: No luck, even tried with you .csv test file, the same error

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input? That makes it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BoarGules tried different .csv files, all give me the same error. I even tried these ones: https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Seemingly your problem boils down to `with open(filename, 'r') as f: x = csv.reader(f)` and x doesn't contain a list of strings. Question is obviously: What does it contain? And maybe you should add some information about the environment, you use.

Comment: I downloaded one of the files from your link. I couldn't guess which one you used. The code you present doesn't work even in Python 2.7. (1) The csv module complains about `new-line character seen in unquoted field`. So I changed your `open()` call to `mode='rU'`. That still didn't work because (2)  the file I downloaded has comma delimiters, and your code specifies `delimiter=';'`. When I fixed that the code ran fine in Python 2.7 and in Python 3.6. So, *not* a Python version issue. Either it's the input, or it's because the code you present isn't the code that is giving the error.

Comment: Rb is read bytes whereas r is read string, so one gives bytes and other gives string

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def load_new_data(self):
    full = list()

    with open(self.filename, 'r') as csv_in:
        myreader2 = csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=';')

        count = 0
        for row in myreader2:
            if count == 0:
                headers = row[1:]
                count += 1
            elif count == 1:
                count += 1
            else:
                current_row = row[1:-1]
                full.append(current_row)
                count += 1

    new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(full, columns=headers)
    new_df = new_df.iloc[1:, :80]

    self.fill_in_blanks(new_df)
    new_df = dp.remove_inc_variables(new_df, .1)
    print ('\t Removing incomplete variables.')

    for i in new_df.columns:
        try:
            new_df.loc[:, i] = new_df.loc[:, i].astype(float)
        except:
            pass
    return new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try codecs, for open file. Be careful this file encoding.
Sample:

```
def load_new_data(self):
    with codecs.open(self.filename, 'rb', encoding="cp1251") as csv_in:  # cp1251 replace for your encoding!
        myreader2 = csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=';') 

        headers = next(myreader2)[1:]
        next(myreader2)

        full = [row[1:] for row in myreader2]

    new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(full, columns=headers)
    new_df = new_df.iloc[1:, :80]

    self.fill_in_blanks(new_df)
    new_df = dp.remove_inc_variables(new_df, .1)
    print('\t Removing incomplete variables.')

    for i in new_df.columns:
        try:
            new_df.loc[:, i] = new_df.loc[:, i].astype(float)
        except:
            pass
    return new_df
```